# passing 3 doubles and a string but my last two variables get ignored by class

Tags: java, string, constructor

Why is my constructor not applying the variables?:

import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

public class Waypoint extends Point2D.Double{

```
private double s;
private String street;

public Waypoint(double x, double y, double s, String street) {
    super(x,y);
    s=9;
    street="Street";
}
   }
```

What is missing here?

Comment: Are you sure that it's printing `At (9.0, 9.0) moving 0.0 MPH on null`? It should print `At (9.0, 9.0) moving 9.0 MPH on Street`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

public class Waypoint extends Point2D.Double{

    private double s;
    private String street;

    public Waypoint(double x, double y, double s, String street) {
        super(x,y);
        s=9;
        street="Street";
    }
```

To

```
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

public class Waypoint extends Point2D.Double{

    private double s;
    private String street;

    public Waypoint(double x, double y, double s, String street) {
        super(x,y);
        this.s = s;
        this.street = street;
    }
```

You are not using the values passed to the constructor.

Comment: I forgot this! Thank you for spotting that

Answer (score 0):

These lines...

```
s=9;
street="Street";
```

...assign values to the local variables corresponding to the arguments of your constructor, while you want to assign them to the fields instead, like this:

```
this.s = s;
this.street = street; // or "Street", if you prefer
```

The `this.` prefix makes the compiler understand that you are referring to the field, and not to the local variable of the same name.